# Adding SSH key while creating Azure VM using python SDK

Tags: python, azure, ssh, key

I'm trying to create an azure vm using the python SDK, and I am able to specify a username and password for the VM, but I am unable to specify an SSH key in order to be able to ssh into the VM I created. Can someone help me out or direct me to any documentation that specifies how to incorporate an SSH key while creating a VM in Azure using Python?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Comment: If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the Python SDK to create the VM, you will use the function [`begin_create_or_update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_03_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#begin-create-or-update-resource-group-name--vm-name--parameters----kwargs-), take a look at the `parameters`, the type is `VirtualMachine`, it means you can define the VM configuration with the `parameters`. And is this parameter you will find the attribute `os_profile`, here you can define the SSH key that copy from your local machine. This is an example:

```
'os_profile': {
      'computer_name': VM_NAME,
      'admin_username': USERNAME,
      "linux_configuration": {
         "disable_password_authentication": True,
         "ssh": {
             "public_keys": [{
                  "path": "/home/{}/.ssh/authorized_keys".format(USERNAME),
                  "key_data": "ssh-rsa ABCD....."
             }]
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach but when I am trying to ssh using pem file it gives error port 22: Operation timed out. Any pointer on this?